# Fresh MySQL Workbench install not responding on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: mysql, macos, installation, osx-lion, mysql-workbench

I have a brand new Macbook Pro with Lion (10.7.4) installed and MySQL (5.5.24). The CLI works fine but when I install MySQL Workbench (5.2.40) the UI is unresponsive.

The only response I can get is the Manage Connections will highlight and allow me to select it when the mouse is about an inch above it's correct location.

I can create a new connection as normal and connect to the DB but cannot close the tab.

This behaviour doesn't work with the Data Modelling or Server Administration section.

I'm pretty familiar with MySQL Workbench on Linux but this Mac problem has me flummoxed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I prefer [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem and was googling for a solution - finding your post as a result. Meanwhile, got the solution myself. Go to /Applications and open info for MySQLWorkbench.app and check there "Open in Low Resolution". It worked for me (a fresh Macbook Pro/Retina@1920x1200).

Comment: That worked on the Retina display @ 1920x1200 as well. Would have never tried it if I didn't read this comment. 

PS: I am running Mountain Lion.

Thanks a lot Jacek

Comment: Worked at treat Jacek, sorry only getting to give the kudos now. Work is crazy at the moment.